# Share website content on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I design my website using html and php and MySQL , i use Open graph Meta tag to share my website on Facebook

```
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="" />
```

I use this meta tag in all page like news and essay , my problem is for example i want to share one of website news on Facebook and i want share correct content , when i try to share , its share content i used in meta tag , i want share my news title, image and content..

my website work dynamically with MySQL and all of my website content like image and text saved in database .

My Question is how dynamically change share content of separate page using Open Graph Meta tag or another thing .

Comment: What your question is?

Comment: @VladimirSerykh my question is how i change mu share content and share correct content ..

Comment: Did you try to output non-empty meta tags with relevant information like `<meta property="og:title" content="Title of the page" />`?

Comment: @VladimirSerykh :) Yes i try .. i mean change <meta property="og:title" content="Title of the Main page" /> to <meta property="og:title" content="Title of the First News" /> ..
 i have one master page and content change ; my url for example like this : http://isatisbc.com/ViewEssay.php?id=17 , when i try share this link show my Open Graph Content , not Essay Title and body ..

Comment: Ok, are you printing different value of the content attribute on different pages?

Comment: All og meta tags are same in your site.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh , my problem is how to set this meta tag according to the content .. I mean change value of this meta tag for each separate page dynamicly .

Comment: @nagiyevel yes i know this Issue , i want set this meta tag for Individually for each page .

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what exacly you want from us.
This can vary depending on how your site script work.
You must set og meta content like how you show page content.
For example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=$page['title'];?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="<?=$page['type'];?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?=$page['image'];?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?=$page['url'];?>" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="<?=$page['admins'];?>" />
```